# How can I do =INDEX(_, MATCH(_, _,0)) of Excel In Stata?

Tags: stata, excel

I would like to use the same concept as `=INDEX(_,MATCH(_,_,0))` of Excel in Stata 12, exclusively using Stata programming.

Is there a way to match one value with a column (say variable A), and then give another column (say variable B) as the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to rely on Stata users knowing what MS Excel functions do: many knowledgeable Stata users don't use MS Excel. Conversely, it's a good idea to put forward your failed attempts. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking on asking good questions.

Can the following be what you want?

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

sysuse auto
keep make foreign

bysort foreign (make) : keep if _n == 1

list, nolabel

*----- what you want ? -----

// two cases
list make if foreign == 1
list make if foreign == 0
```

Run `findit vlookup`, for a user-written command that does just that, but in Stata.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `merge` command. Type `help merge` for an explanation.